# org-table processing in csharp org-babel src block

Tags: org-babel

I've got working org-table input in elisp and c++, but this can work in c#, too?

Here's how it works for C++:

```
#+name: somedata
| nb    | sqr | noise |
|-------+-----+-------|
| zero  |   0 |  0.23 |
| one   |   1 |  1.31 |
| two   |   4 |  4.61 |
| three |   9 |  9.05 |
| four  |  16 | 16.55 |

#+begin_src C++ :var somedata=somedata :includes '("<string>" "<typeinfo>" "<iostream>")
  std::string types= typeid(somedata).name();
  std::cout<<types<<":"<<somedata[2][2];
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: A5_A3_PKc:4.61
```

Here's what I get for C#

```
#+name: somedata
| nb    | sqr | noise |
|-------+-----+-------|
| zero  |   0 |  0.23 |
| one   |   1 |  1.31 |
| two   |   4 |  4.61 |
| three |   9 |  9.05 |
| four  |  16 | 16.55 |

//#+name: c-table
//#+header: :exports results

#+begin_src csharp :var somedata=somedata
System.Console.WriteLine(somedata[2][2]);
#+end_src
```

```
/tmp/babel-kJp1QT/csharp-src-WFTFBX.csx(1,26): error CS0103: The name 'somedata' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: You mean, write a src block in C# that reads that table? I'm sure it can be done, assuming that there is a C# Org babel back end. I didn't know if one existed, but a search found [this](https://github.com/thomas-villagers/ob-csharp) - maybe that's good enough, or maybe there are other backends if not.

Comment: The actual org-babel implementation for that particular language has to implement the header values mentioned here: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html  ?

Comment: Yes: part of that implementation is in `ob-core.el`: see the function `org-babel--get-vars`. But the implementation has to call that function and do something with the variables. For an example, see how `ob-C.el` calls the above  function and how it handles the variables. It seems that the implementation I pointed you to does not do that. I don't know if there is another implementation that is more complete.